# Sampling from a contingency table

Tags: r, sample, contingency

I've managed as far as the code below in writing a function to sample from a contingency table - proportional to the frequencies in the cells.

It uses `expand.grid` and then `table` to get back to the original size table. Which works fine as long as the sample size is large enough that some categories are not completely missing. Otherwise the `table` command returns a table that is of smaller dimensions than the original one.

```
FunSample<- function(Full, n) {
  Frame <- expand.grid(lapply(dim(Full), seq))
  table(Frame[sample(1:nrow(Frame), n, prob = Full, replace = TRUE), ])
}
Full<-array(c(1,2,3,4), dim=c(2,2,2))
FunSample(Full, 100) # OK
FunSample(Full, 1) # not OK, I want it to still have dim=c(2,2,2)!
```

My brain has stopped working, I know it has to be a small tweak to get it back on track!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crosstab is also a multinomial distribution, so you can use `rmultinom` and reset the dimension on the output. This should give a substantial performance boost and cut down on the code you need to maintain.

```
> X <- rmultinom(1, 500, Full)
> dim(X) <- dim(Full)
> X
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   18   92
[2,]   45   92

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   28   72
[2,]   49  104

> X2 <-rmultinom(1, 4, Full)
> dim(X2) <- dim(Full)
> X2
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks Neal, that is a beautiful and elegant solution, I've changed the answer to yours!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want `table()` to "drop" missing combinations, you need to force the columns of `Frame` to be factors:

```
FunSample <- function(Full, n) {
  Frame <- as.data.frame( lapply( expand.grid(lapply(dim(Full), seq)), factor) )  
  table( Frame[sample(1:nrow(Frame), n, prob = Full, replace = TRUE), ])
}   

> dim( FunSample(Full, 1))
[1] 2 2 2
> dim( FunSample(Full, 100))
[1] 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tabulate` instead of `table`; it works on integer-valued vectors, as you have here.  You could also get the output into an array by using `array` directly, just like when you created the original data.

```
FunSample<- function(Full, n) {
  samp <- sample(1:length(Full), n, prob = Full, replace = TRUE)
  array(tabulate(samp), dim=dim(Full))
}
```